# Не обновляется вид на странице при добавлении нового элемента

Tags: javascript, библиотеки, knockoutjs

Изучаю библиотеку knockout и столкнулся с пробемой. При добавлении нового элемента в ko.observableArray методом push(), на странице ничего не обновляется. Не могу понять почему? Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/95Q45/
Хочу сделать так: если что-нибудь написать в поле *"имя"* и нажать на ссылку *"добавить"*, то должен обновиться список над input'ом с новым значением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте:

```
studentsList: {
    foreach: students
},
```

на:

```
studentsList: {
    foreach: self.students
},
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так заработало. Странно(для меня), что без "self." он вообще этот список строит. Надо будет покопаться в этом вопросе.

Comment: @ZondArt, извините, с этим не помогу, т.к. Knockout.js первый раз увидел